# Mathematica reacts to a wrong condition in a weird way

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, algebra

With apologies, I evaluated the eigenvalues of a matrix under a  condition which included wrongly some Falses. The weird result was a failure to obtain the eigenvalues?

`````
    ````
      J = {{-\[Gamma]e - \[Mu], \[Beta], 0, 
    0}, {\[Gamma]e, -\[Gamma]i - \[Delta] - \[Mu], 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, \[Gamma]i - \[Gamma]r - \[Mu], 
    0}, {0, -\[Beta], \[Gamma]r, -\[Mu]}};
Print["matrix=", J // MatrixForm, " det =  ", 
  det = Det[J] // FullSimplify, "ch pol=", 
  CharacteristicPolynomial[J, \[Xi]] // FullSimplify];
cp = {\[Mu] > 0, 
   False, \[Beta] > 0, \[Gamma]e > 0, \[Gamma]i > 0, \[Gamma]r > 0, 
   False, \[Delta] > 0};
eig = FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[J], Assumptions -> cp];
eig[[1]]
eig[[2]]
eig[[3]]
eig[[4]]
eig[[1]] == eig[[2]]
    ````
`````

The first two eigenvalues are given as equal. They come from the last quadratic factor, and of course, they shouldn't be equal.

Comment: Eigensystem[J] shows all eigenvalues are different. Also characteristic polynomial contains only linear factors, which proves that all eigenvalues should be different . So everything is consistent.

Comment: your code uses eig which is not defined and I don't understand what eig[[4]] could be?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy one line. After correcting,  the error became clear, I was evaluating  the eigs under  a condition which included False (unknowingly). I'm still curious why Mathematica reacted the way it did.